# KeyError username when pulling json data in python script

Tags: python

```html
 {
        "id": 553946,
        "url": "http://www.tvmaze.com/episodes/553946/stranger-things-1x01-chapter-one-the-vanishing-of-will-byers",
        "name": "Chapter One: The Vanishing of Will Byers",
        "season": 1,
        "number": 1,
        "airdate": "2016-07-15",
        "airtime": "",
        "airstamp": "2016-07-15T12:00:00+00:00",
        "runtime": 60,
        "critique": [
            {
   "username": "Cloe",
            "votes": 
            {
    "funny": 1,
    "useful": 6,
    "cool": 3
   },
   "text": "My favourite episode by far! Love the dramatic lighting and sounds",
   "rating": 5,
   "date": "2009-12-24",
   "_id": {
    "$oid": "58b4394ed256330fdad6fa63"
   }
      }

        ],
        "image": {
            "medium": "http://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/medium_landscape/67/168918.jpg",
            "original": "http://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/original_untouched/67/168918.jpg"
        },
        "summary": "A young boy mysteriously disappears, and his panicked mother demands that the police find him. Meanwhile, the boy's friends conduct their own search, and meet a mysterious girl in the forest.",
        "_links": {
            "self": {
                "href": "http://api.tvmaze.com/episodes/553946"
            }
        }
    }
```

I have a json data set for tv episodes with critiques nested within each episode. Im writing a python method that will pull all the critiques from my json data out (without the episode attribtes) I can get the ID but cant seem to get the username, despite this being the name of the attribute in the json data set. I keep seeing keyerror: 'username'

```js
@app.route("/api/v1.0/critiques", methods=["GET"])
def show_all_critiques():
    page_num, page_size = 1, 100
    if request.args.get("pn"):
        page_num = int(request.args.get('pn'))
    if request.args.get("ps"):
        page_size = int(request.args.get('ps'))
    page_start = (page_size * (page_num-1))

    data_to_return = []
    for critique in episodes.find({}, {"username": 1, "text": 1, "rating": 1, "date": 1}
    ).skip(page_start).limit(page_size):
            critique ["_id"] = str(critique["_id"]),
            critique ["username"] = str(critique["username"])
            data_to_return.append(critique)

    return make_response(jsonify(data_to_return),200)
```

Comment: You have a comma at the end of the `critique["_id"]` assignment?

Comment: Are you sure there is always a "username" key for every element in array ? Try with this check before assignment : `critique["username"] = str(critique["username"]) if "username" in critique else None`.

Comment: Thanks for the response! So when I include this check, the value for all instances of username returns as null, but im 100% that many of the critiques have usernames within them, some more than 1?